# Uso de métodos estáticos en un Interface Java con genéricos (operador diamante)

Tags: java, genericos

Estoy creando un CRUD con varias implementaciones. Para ello tengo una clase **Categoria**, una interfaz **RepositorioI** y una implementación de la interfaz **CategoriaRepositorioLista** (la idea es hacer diferentes implementaciones, tanto con listas, Bases de Datos tradicionales e Hibernate).

Hasta la fecha tenía la interfaz parametrizada con el operador diamante hacia el tipo del modelo, y los métodos como método de instancia. Luego pensé que, realmente, no tengo necesidad de crear una instancia de la implementación del repositorio porque no voy a utilizar atributos de instancia.

Si tengo un atributo, va a ser estático pues sólo lo voy a utilizar a nivel de clase. Lo que pase a los métodos o me devuelvan estos no se va a almacenar internamente.

La interfaz originalmente tenía este aspecto:

RepositorioI.java

```
package com.anubedam.repositorio.interfaces;

import java.util.List;

public interface RepositorioI<T> {
    /* Repositorio con las operaciones CRUD */
    
    // Guardar el modelo
    void guardar(T modelo);
        
    // Recuperar un modelo por su id
    T buscarPorId(long id);
    
    // Recuperar todos los modelos
    List<T> buscarTodos();
    
    // Borrar el modelo
    void borrarPorId(long id);    
    
    // Borrar todos los modelos
    void borrarTodos();  
}
```

El problema es cuando decido hacer los métodos de la interfaz estáticos.

```
package com.anubedam.repositorio.interfaces;

import java.util.List;

public interface RepositorioI<T> {
    /* Repositorio con las operaciones CRUD */
    
    // Guardar el modelo
    static void guardar(T modelo);
        
    // Recuperar un modelo por su id
    static T buscarPorId(long id);
    
    // Recuperar todos los modelos
    static List<T> buscarTodos();
    
    // Borrar el modelo
    static void borrarPorId(long id);    
    
    // Borrar todos los modelos
    static void borrarTodos();  
}
```

El error que me está dando, en todos los métodos, es

> non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static
> context

Es decir, que el tipo que se asocia con la interfaz es a nivel de instancia y en principio no puedo utilizar métodos estáticos con el operador diamante.

Realmente lo que yo quiero hacer es evitar el uso de tipo Object y tener que preguntar si es una instancia de tal clase o de otra y hacer casteos.

No pongo la clase del modelo ni de la implementación de la interfaz porque de lo que realmente se está quejando es de la interfaz.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo en este caso? He estado buscando por internet y no he encontrado cómo poder resolver este problema.

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Solución: No uses métodos estáticos, por varios motivos, pero sobre todo porque no puedes doblar esa dependencia (test double) en entornos de test.

Comment: Si realmente necesitas estáticos deberás declarar el genérico en el método y no en la clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede con los genéricos es que el type erasure funciona a nivel de instancia, para que funcione con estáticos tendrías que declarar el type erasure en cada método estático. Por ejemplo, guardar tendría que ser así:

```
   static <T> void guardar (T modelo){}
```

Ojo, en Java no existen los métodos estáticos abstractos, tienes que implementarlos. También debes tener en cuenta que  en guardar podría ser EntidadA, y en buscarPorId podría ser EntidadB, en cambio si los pones como métodos abstractos (sin static), si la  de la implementación es EntidadA, se mantiene para todos los métodos.

Ahora, yo me pregunto, ¿para qué quieres hacer todo estático? Quizás sea una mejor opción usar abstract class, o proveer una implementación por defecto para algunos métodos:

```
default void guardar(T modelo){
   //Ha algo para grabar que sea común en todas las implementaciones
}
```

Comment: Llevo el último año y medio trabajando con Angular+Node, y estoy acostumbrado a que las interfaces tengan métodos públicos y abstractos (aunque realmente no tienen una representación real al transpilar a Vanilla JS). Estaba refrescando mi Java y haciendo un CRUD con varias implementaciones.

Comment: Se me ocurrió que como realmente no voy a necesitar variables de instancia para mi repositorio, ya que todas las variables o van a ser a nivel de clase o devuelven un nuevo objeto y/o reciben un objeto pero que no se almacena internamente como una instancia independiente, utilizar una interfaz con métodos estáticos.

Comment: ¿Por qué una interfaz y no una clase abstracta? No quería gastar el cartucho de la herencia y, realmente, no tenía necesidad de un método no abstracto que tenga una implementación que quiera que sea heredada. Por otra parte, así podía practicar la programación orientada a interfaces. Gracias por la respuesta.